# What would be the minimum fissile material needed to start fusion within a pulse unit?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I am trying to calculate the weight of the pulse unit and composition and the approximate fallout, for a ground launch in regards to Project Orion`s nuclear pulse propulsion for a 0.03 kiloton and 0.35 kiloton detonation. The fusion of Deuterium (or another) would be primary focus so that the lowest possible amount of fallout is generated from the launch.

Comment: Starting fusion is irrelevant - what you need to calculate is the energy required to lift your spacecraft and the percent energy of a well-designed shaped-charge bomb that will produce force in the desired direction.

Comment: If it was a pure fusion explosion inside a mass of boronated water there would be almost no fallout. The problem is "pure fusion"

Comment: 'A bomb with a cylinder of reaction mass expands into a flat, disk-shaped wave of plasma when it explodes. A bomb with a disk-shaped reaction mass expands into a far more efficient cigar-shaped wave of plasma debris. The cigar shape focuses much of the plasma to impinge onto the pusher-plate.' project Orion wiki page, +80% of the plasma generated will impinge the pusher plate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are asking for the minimum fissile material needed to build a  nuclear bomb. [This site](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/News/DoSuitcaseNukesExist.html) might help with some of that. However, it seems likely that the real answers are classified. I have heard that a nuke can be created using as little as 1kg of Plutonium. I also saw a reference to a Polish paper during the Cold War that suggested it might be possible to go as low as 100 grams, although it sounds dubious.

Comment: Dirk, you've said too much already.  Look out for black helicopters!